# How to grep for specific string in a file

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, grep, text-processing

this is my input file

```
<MessageOut>
<Attribute name="Session-Id" value="22250"/><Attribute name="CC-Request-Type" value="2"/><Attribute name="CC-Request-Number" value="1"/><Attribute name="Origin-Host" value="indlnqw291"/><Attribute name="Origin-Realm" value="amdocs.com"/><Attribute name="Auth-Application-Id" value="4"/><Attribute name="Result-Code" value="5031"/><Attribute name="CC-Session-Failover" value="1"/><Attribute name="Low-Balance-Indication" value="0"/><Attribute name="Multiple-Services-Credit-Control"><Group><Attribute name="Result-Code" value="5031"/><Attribute name="Service-Identifier" value="0"/><Attribute name="Rating-Group" value="2"/></Group></Attribute></MessageOut>
<MessageOut>
<Attribute name="Session-Id" value="22250"/><Attribute name="CC-Request-Type" value="3"/><Attribute name="CC-Request-Number" value="2"/><Attribute name="Origin-Host" value="indlnqw291"/><Attribute name="Origin-Realm" value="amdocs.com"/><Attribute name="Auth-Application-Id" value="4"/><Attribute name="Result-Code" value="5031"/></MessageOut>
<MessageOut>
<Attribute name="Session-Id" value="22250"/><Attribute name="CC-Request-Type" value="1"/><Attribute name="CC-Request-Number" value="0"/><Attribute name="Origin-Host" value="indlnqw291"/><Attribute name="Origin-Realm" value="amdocs.com"/><Attribute name="Auth-Application-Id" value="4"/><Attribute name="Result-Code" value="5031"/><Attribute name="CC-Session-Failover" value="1"/><Attribute name="Low-Balance-Indication" value="0"/><Attribute name="Multiple-Services-Credit-Control"><Group><Attribute name="Result-Code" value="5031"/><Attribute name="Service-Identifier" value="0"/><Attribute name="Rating-Group" value="2"/></Group></Attribute></MessageOut>
```

i want grep result code  after "Multiple-Services-Credit-Control"

expected result:

```
"CC-Request-Type" value="1"
"CC-Request-Number" value="0"
"Result-Code" value="5031"

"CC-Request-Type" value="2"
"CC-Request-Number" value="1"
"Result-Code" value="5031"

"CC-Request-Type" value="3"
"CC-Request-Number" value="2"
"Result-Code" value="5031"
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You tagged this with `sed` and `grep`, but neither of these tools were designed to handle structured markup, which is generally too complex for standard unix filters. While your specific use case *might* be doable, I'd probably just use an XML parsing library from your favorite language

Comment: Have you tryed anything so far? SO is not a place for I have this, I expect this and wait for it to happen'. Please post what you've tryed.

Comment: i tried with below cmd it working fine if i grep singe message out session but i can't use for 3 session


sed -n -e 's/^.*Multiple-Services-Credit-Control//p' xml.txt | sed -n -e 's/^.*Result-Code" value=//p' |  cut -d'"' -f2

Comment: Why not create a Perl script and read data line by line?

Comment: actually i'm not aware perl , please suggest me which one is best perl, unix or xmllint for this job

Comment: Any tool that supports xpath should do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'path_to_input_file\data.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp $row;
    $row =~ /.*?("CC-Request-Type"\svalue="\d*").*?("CC-Request-Number"\svalue="\d*").*?("Result-Code" value="\d*")/;
    if ( (defined $1) and (defined $2) and (defined $3)){
        print "\n$1\n$2\n$3\n";
    }
}
```

This is the solution in Perl. If you need explanations for the reg-ex used I will gladly exlpain it.

Comment: Yes, the script will read each line from the input file. After that it will search for the pattern. I used groups to catch the information, what you see inside the paranthesses, those are groupings. ` $_ ` will store the information in the order of the paranthesses from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

This is `XML`. [It's a bad idea to try and use regular expressions on `XML`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), because `XML` is contextual, and regular expressions aren't.

Use an XML Parser. Most will let you do `xpath` which is comparable to regular expressions - but specifically designed to handle the contextual nature of `XML`.

`perl` has multiple options. I like `XML::Twig` particularly.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> parsefile ( 'your_file.xml' );

my @attributes = qw ( CC-Request-Type CC-Request-Number Result-Code );

foreach my $msg ( $twig -> get_xpath('//MessageOut') ) {
    foreach my $attribute ( @attributes ) {
        print "$attribute value=",$msg -> get_xpath("//Attribute[\@name=\'$attribute\']",0)->att('value'),"\n"; 
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

With your sample data (slightly amended to include root tags) give:

```
CC-Request-Type value=2
CC-Request-Number value=1
Result-Code value=5031

CC-Request-Type value=2
CC-Request-Number value=1
Result-Code value=5031

CC-Request-Type value=2
CC-Request-Number value=1
Result-Code value=5031
```

Comment: Good asnwer. I was using the "line pattern" from the question, but this is working in all contexts.

Comment: Yes. I didn't downvote it, because it does solve the problem, but I honestly believe that regexing XML is creating future problems.